Maven - Unable to process dependency X due to zip file is empty
When trying to run a mvn verify I'm encountering the following:
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (no-duplicate-classes) @ commons ---
[INFO] Adding ignore: module-info
[INFO] Adding ignore: META-INF/versions/*/module-info
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanDuplicateClasses failed with message:
Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanDuplicateClasses failed with message:


Unable to process dependency org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.25.RELEASE:compile due to zip file is empty

My Maven configuration for BanDuplicateClasses is as follows:
<projects>

    <!-- ... dependencies omitted but included spring boot 2.7 ... -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- ... other plugins ... -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>no-duplicate-classes</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <banDuplicateClasses>
                                    <findAllDuplicates>true</findAllDuplicates>
                                    <ignoreWhenIdentical>true</ignoreWhenIdentical>
                                </banDuplicateClasses>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Computer is MacOS with project in Java 11 and Maven 3.8.4
What is it complaining about? And how do I fix it?

First you are using old Maven version, also very old plugin versions (enforcer 1.X??) ...please check https://maven.apache.org/plugins/, Spring Boot version etc... but I would suggest to try mvn -U ... .... also turn on your checksum policy to at least WARN better to fail.. (https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#repositories) also check here: https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2018/10/2018-10-13-maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Turns out the .jar file in my ~/.m2/repository/ existed but was empty (0 bytes) thus the error message:

... zip file is empty

Note that mvn clean doesn't touch this file it seems.
Thus the fix was to "hand delete the file":

Navigate to the directory cd ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.25.RELEASE

Verify the file is empty (0 bytes) with ls -alh (notice the .jar file is 0B)
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   7 me  staff   224B Sep  3 16:44 ./
drwxr-xr-x  24 me  staff   768B Sep  3 17:07 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff   218B Sep  3 16:44 _remote.repositories
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff     0B Sep  3 16:44 spring-beans-5.2.25.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff    40B Sep  3 16:44 spring-beans-5.2.25.RELEASE.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff   1.6K Sep  3 16:43 spring-beans-5.2.25.RELEASE.pom
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff    40B Sep  3 16:43 spring-beans-5.2.25.RELEASE.pom.sha1



Hard remove that file rm -rf spring-beans-5.2.25.RELEASE.jar

Rerun mvn verify which should download the file as needed


TL;DR: ... zip file is empty might require a direct file delete as Maven seems to not be able to correct some non-downloaded files.
